# how can I get the value of %APPDATA% using JScript?

Tags: environment-variables, javascript, userappdatapath

how can I get the value (path) of %APPDATA% in Micorosoft JScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WScript.Shell object provides the property Environment.

see also: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/233513/en-us/

Comment: Thanks Harper..

The following piece of code worked for me

var WshShell = Sys.OleObject("WScript.Shell");
var WshSysEnv = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%");